# Elastic Search Scripting Hour Minute

Tags: elasticsearch, time, filter, expression

This behavior of running script with elastic search is quite puzzling to me. I am running a script to filter by time. I have got these methods from this [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting-expression.html).

This script with HoursOfDay works (**date.hourOfDay**)

```
{
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "expression",
            "source": "doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay >= min && doc['@timestamp'].date.hourOfDay <= max",
            "params": {
              "min": 5,
              "max": 8
            }
          }
        }          
      }
```

Whereas, the script with Minutes doesnt return any results. **(date.minuteOfDay)**

```
{
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "expression",
            "source": "doc['@timestamp'].date.minuteOfDay >= min && doc['@timestamp'].date.minuteOfDay <= max",
            "params": {
              "min": 300,
              "max": 480
            }
          }
        }          
      }
```

Also i have tried few other way from this [elastic document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html) by using "**date.getHourOfDay()**" and "**date.getMinutes()**", and found similar behavior.  getHourOfDay returns results and getMinutes() doesnt.

Am I missing something here or is there a specific configuration at the elastic level to enable this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in source you can try params.min and params.max instead min and max respectively

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why would it then work with hourOfDay. The syntax is correct as per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-using)

Comment: min and max are not accessible directly as it bound to scope of params